# Store input data on /opt/ml/ of container using AWS Step Functions

Tags: python-3.x, docker, amazon-sagemaker, aws-step-functions

I am following [this](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/step-functions-data-science-sdk/automate_model_retraining_workflow/automate_model_retraining_workflow.ipynb) tutorial to setup a re-training of the Prophet model on a Docker image that is stored on ECR.

When I get to the Training_Step, this setup is not able to put the input data to the /opt/ml/input/data folder on the docker container. I can pick it up from the S3 folder, but since the training is happening on the container and it needs the input data to be present in the /opt/ml... location, the AWS Step Function setup is failing at the Training_Step.

Any inputs on how to push the input data collected from S3 to the docker container (/opt/ml/input/data) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sage-maker notebooks in order to run the estimator of docker image you can use the inputs command in order to direct your opt/ml/input/data folder to the corresponding s3 link. Here's how can you configure that part:

Update your S3 link's like this:

S3_TRAIN_DATA = 's3_link_for_your_training_data'

S3_VAL_DATA = 's3_link_for_your_validation_data

Create your estimator based on the image uri for docker image
and then use your inputs like this:

inputs={
'train':S3_TRAIN_DATA,
'val':S3_VAL_DATA
}

remember your data path to the model in this case would be

a.)opt/ml/input/data/train

b.)opt/ml/input/data/val